# Can I use New Relic for google-style analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, newrelic

My google analytics is not tracking reliably and I use New Relic.  Is there a way to generate New Relic reports with number of pageviews/visitors/etc?

Answer (score 4):

New Relic Insights is the product best suited to user analytics. It can track unique visitors if you've got a user ID recorded in your events, show funnel charts, and offers a lot of flexible query power.

Real User Monitoring (now the Browser product) would give you information on page views and details of individual browser sessions, but it's meant for front-end performance monitoring, not so much for user analytics.